# TFS Client APIs for creating workitem templates?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-sdk

Of course, it is pretty possible to create work items, get a list of work items etc in TFS.

In addition to this, we need to have the functionality of allowing our users to create their own work item templates, for various file types.

Whether the TFS Client APIs are capable of uploading work item templates to TFS server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a method to get the (XML) definition: [`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemType.Export`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemtype.export.aspx)

And, [`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemTypeCollection.Import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemtypecollection.import.aspx) which looks like you can upload XML to create a new work item type.

Suggestion, set up a VM with an instance of TFS Workgroup and perform lots of testing.